# How do I get the date and time and display it in a defineProps?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a simple VueJS application and I would like to display todays date and time and define it in DefineProps, I've tried the following in my component:

I would like to display todays date and time and define it in DefineProps, I've tried the following in my component:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  dateandtime: String
})
</script>
```

And in my view I have the following:

```
<Header dateandtime="test" />
```

I also tried putting new Date().toLocaleString() next to the dateandtime prop and I atleast expected something out of it but that didn't work so easy.

Comment: Why do you need to pass it as props? Can't you just display the today's date and time in your Header component using new Date().toLocaleString()

Comment: @IP002 Because later on I want to add more props and be able to change this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass date as props you have to generate your date in the parent component in this case `App.vue`. The `defineProps` only serves as an interface to structure our props and define their types, defaults or if they're required. Depending on how you want to pass your `date` props, I have defined both `String` and `Date` as acceptable prop types in `Header.vue`. Here is how you can do it:

`App.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Header from './Header.vue';

const todaysDate = ref(new Date().toLocaleString());
</script>

<template>
  <Header :date="todaysDate"></Header>  
  <Header :date="new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')"></Header>  
</template>
```

`Header.vue`

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    date: [String, Date],
})
</script>

<template>
    <h2>{{ date }}</h2>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, update your component to pass the current date and time as a prop:

```
    <!-- Header.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ dateandtime }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  dateandtime: String,
});
</script>
```

Now, in the parent component where you use Header, you can calculate the current date and time and pass it as a prop:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header :dateandtime="currentDateTime" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Header from './Header.vue';

const currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
</script>
```